# C access symbol in executable (linux)

Tags: c, linux, symbols

I have an executable binary with many symbols. I am trying to figure out how to access those symbols in my code. dbg can so I know its possible im just not sure how. I cannot create a shared object from it with "gcc -shared -o myexe.so myexe" because there are multiple definitions of the same function

```
...(.data+0x8e8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: error in fipstest(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
/usr/bin/ld: fipsttest.so: No symbol version section for versioned symbol `NSSUTIL_ArgGetLabel@@NSSUTIL_3.14'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This means that gcc cannot link to it during compile time with -L because the of the same issue. 
the nm command shows all the symbols and the one I want. If I could modify the symbol table to remove all the exports but the ONE I need then it might work but I can't find how to do that. Or if anyone could point me in the right direction to access a binary during runtime and load a function with a physical address that would work too. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not quite following.  You're starting with what, an ELF executable?  And you want to make a shared library out of it?  That's a bit backward.  The other direction is a lot more natural.

Comment: well It doesn't need to be a legit shared object. Yes this isn't the easiest way. I am testing compiled code for a government standard and it can never be recompiled

Comment: Well, if you need to test the executable as it stands, then it seems to me that you shouldn't modify its symbol table, either.  If it's a position-independent executable then you might be able to link it as a library directly, or load it with `dlopen()` and execute functions within with the help of `dlsym()`.

Comment: thanks for the pointer ! I will look into those